# Ruby - Inherit Method Order

Tags: ruby, inheritance, methods, super

Is there a way to do this?

```
class Parent
  def stuff
    #error checking that needs to go first
  end
end

class Young < Parent
  def stuff
    super
    p 'doing new stuff here'
  end
end
```

This code sees to call the parent method via super, and then it never returns to the "doing new stuff" part.

Comment: It does return to the `'doing new stuff here'` part. Maybe the actual code exits or raises an exception.

Comment: oh okay.  do you want to add that as an answer i can accept? should i delete my post?

Comment: You can delete it if you want, or you can let the community close it as *No longer reproducible*.

Comment: yeah, delete it. Now it has no value whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance can get hairy sometimes and prone to errors.  Unless you have a lot of children that are using specific actions of the "Parent" class, I recommend you simply capture all of the actions you want in a module and include by using a mixin.  It is much easier and straightforward.

```
module Stuff
  def check_errors
    #error checking that needs to go first
  end
end

class Young
  include Stuff

  check_errors
  p 'doing new stuff here'
end
```

Comment: So you are advising towards always using mixins instead of inheritance, unless *"you have a lot of children that are using specific actions of the "Parent" class"*?

Comment: Didn't say always. His example seemed to be unnecessarily using inheritance. I'm advising that mixins are more straight forward. If you can get what you want by using a mixin, I recommend you do.

Comment: Everything that can be done with inheritance can also be done with mixins. Saying you should use one or the other unless you don't have a choice is too broad of a generalization to make. Also since the question aimed towards understanding how inheritance works, giving an alternative doesn't answer the question IMO.

Comment: @ndn I see what you mean. My stand point is helping the asker walk away with an understanding of what he's trying to accomplish. Whatever makes that happen is an answer. Mixins IMO are easier to understand and more 'plug and play' than inheritance. With that said, thank you for your opinion and your helping me to learn the appropriate stack-etiquette.

Comment: there is a nice talk by Sandi Metz on drawbacks of inheritance https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMPfEXIlTVE although in this talk she used dependency injection for solving the issue  ;)